# Disable submit button if checkbox is not checked in flask/html/python

Tags: python, html, button, onclick, submit

I am making a quiz sort function with **python**, **html** and **flask**. I need to make sure that an answer with the radio buttons is selected before letting the user click the submit function.

This is the python code for the function and html for button:

```
     def EnableSubmit():

        sbmt = document.getElementById('submit-button')
        if val.checked == True:
           sbmt.disabled = False
        else:
           sbmt.disabled = True
```

HTML:

```
<div>
       {% for elem in song_options %}
            <input type="radio" name="song" value = "{{elem}}"> {{elem}} <br>
       {% endfor %}
</div>
<br>
<div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" onClick="EnableSubmit(this)">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "songandartist" value = "{{song_name , song_artist}}">
```

Comment: It should be 'True" and 'False' with a capital letter. Also, you can eliminate the if-else block by doing 'sbmt.disabled = not val.checked'

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Do I need (this) in parentheses? its still not working

Comment: Could you please provide more context? Like, What is val(I understand it's a Radio button element) and where is it initialized and the full HTML and Python code

Comment: I have included more of the HTML, I am trying to make sure one of the radio buttons with value elem is selected.    Am I suppose to do elem.checked == True. Also am I suppose to button.getElementId

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 def EnableSubmit():
 sbmt = document.getElementById('submit-button')
 if val.checked == True && document != null:
      sbmt.disabled = False
 else:
     sbmt.disabled = True
```